# List of interfaces with generic return type

Tags: c#, generics, interface, return-type

```
interface IFly<T>
    {
        T GetMark();
    }

    public class Bird : IFly<string>
    {
        public string GetMark()
        {
            return "Bird";
        }
    }

    public class Plane : IFly<int>
    {
        public int GetMark()
        {
            return 123;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IFly<string> bird = new Bird();
            IFly<int> plane = new Plane();

            Console.WriteLine(bird.GetMark());
            Console.WriteLine(plane.GetMark());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

I would like to replace this

```
IFly<string> bird = new Bird();
IFly<int> plane = new Plane();
```

with something like this:

```
var fly = new List<IFly<T>>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The only concrete common denominator for those two types `Bird` and `Plane` is `object` so you'd need a `List<object>`

Comment: @RuneFS, yup!  and he won't be able to do anything useful with them without casting explicitly, either.  Unless `GetMark` returned an object.

Comment: Also, this sounds like the XY problem - there's something else the OP is designing/trying to solve and this hints at a dodgy design decision somewhere.

Comment: @RuneFS, how do I add object to a list?

var fly = new List<IFly<object>>();
            
`IFly<string> bird = new Bird();
IFly<int> plane = new Plane();
fly.Add(???);`

Comment: @ile, he means you can do `var fly = new List<object>()`, then `fly.Add(new Bird())`. This is really no different than the answer I gave below - except that in the answer below the only thing the list can contain is objects that implement `IFlyRoot`, instead of any object under the sun. Either way, they're both not very useful for what you're probably attempting to accomplish.

Comment: @Steve, when I do `fly.Add(new Bird())` then I get error: Cannot convert from 'TestApp.Bird' to 'TestApp.IFly<object>'

Comment: +1 for simple straightforward way of asking. -1 since this is duplicated many times.

Comment: Suppose you could do that. **What would you do with the list when you had it?** You can't call `fly[0].GetMark()` because the compiler would not know whether an `int` or a `string` or some completely other type was being put on the stack!

Answer (score 3):

This might work:

```
public interface IFlyRoot { }

interface IFly<T> : IFlyRoot
{
    T GetMark();
}
```

Then you can make a `List<IFlyRoot>`.

Comment: It would however the method `GetMark` wouldn't be accessible unless you cast the item of the list to `IFly<T>`

Comment: Ah, good point. It does accomplish what the OP asked, even if it's not terribly useful :)

Comment: @Steve, agreed... but +1 as `List<IFlyRoot>` is still better than a `List<object>`

Comment: and how can I call GetMark() method?

Comment: `var list = new List<IFlyRoot>();
            list.Add(new Bird());
            list.Add(new Plane());

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.GetMark());
            }`

In this case `GetMark()` is not accessible. Any suggestions how to cast?

Comment: Not really. You could simply make `GetMark()` return an object, if `ToString()` is all you're looking for. Every object implements `ToString()`.

Answer (score 2):

In general case @Steve's answer is the right one. However, depending on your needs you could try using type variance, but it doesn't support value types (`int` wouldn't work).

Notice the `out` in interface definition:

```
interface IFly<out T>
{
    T GetMark();
}
```

Then you are allowed to write:

```
var list = new List<IFly<object>>();
list.Add(bird);
```

but it won't work with `Plane`, where `T` is a value type (here: `int`). This solution may not suit your exact needs then.

To get more insight into *why* variance doesn't work with value types refer to answers of [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12454932/318795) or [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4098434/318795). In short, it's because reference identity should be preserved, but with value types it cannot. A value type would always be boxed first, loosing that identity. That's why it doesn't work automatically. There's not really a clean way around this. One thing you could try is to make `Plane` class explicitly implement `IFly<object>` as well:

```
public class Plane : IFly<int>, IFly<object>
{
    public int GetMark()
    {
        return 123;
    }

    object IFly<object>.GetMark()
    {
        return GetMark();
    }
}
```

And add to list:

```
list.Add(new Plane());
```

Comment: If you then do something like `var mark = list.First().GetMark()`, `mark` will be of type `object`, not `string`, and will need to be cast.

Comment: Yep, looks like out fixed error message. Any suggestion how to deal with int? And why it's not working with int?

Comment: @ile: Please see my extended answer.

Comment: @Steve: that's true, but then there's no point in using variance. It's whole purpose is to be able to operate on common base of objects of different types without casting. It's most visible with a more complex class hierarchy. If you need to deal with members of the most derived type ('string' here in example), just keep a `List<IFly<string>>`. The cost of sticking to `IFly<object>` is lack of direct access to string members, but this gives you flexibility in processing objects in a 'common denominator' way.

Answer (score 0):

Since IFly and IFly are considered different types by the CLR you will need to establish a more direct relationship between the two, in this case by implementing a non-generic version of the interface IFly.  The collection would then store objects as long as they implement this common interface for example:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var flyingThings = new ThingsThatFlyCollection();
        var bird = new Bird();
        var bird2 = new Bird();
        var plane = new Plane();

        flyingThings.Add(bird);
        flyingThings.Add(bird2);
        flyingThings.Add(plane);

        Console.WriteLine(flyingThings.GetItemWithCast<string>(0).GetMark());
        Console.WriteLine(flyingThings.GetItemWithCast<string>(1).GetMark());
        Console.WriteLine(flyingThings.GetItemWithCast<int>(2).GetMark());

        foreach (var item in flyingThings.GetItemsWithCast<int>()) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.GetMark());
        }

        foreach (var item in flyingThings.GetItemsWithCast<string>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.GetMark());
        }

        foreach (var item in flyingThings.GetItemsByType<Bird>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.GetMark());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IFly
{
    object GetMark();
}

public interface IFly<TMark> : IFly
{
    new TMark GetMark();
}

class Plane : IFly<int>
{
    public int GetMark() { return 123; }
    object IFly.GetMark() { return this.GetMark(); }
}

class Bird : IFly<string>
{
    public string GetMark() { return "Bird"; }
    object IFly.GetMark() { return this.GetMark(); }
}

class ThingsThatFlyCollection : Collection<IFly>
{
    public IFly<TMark> GetItemWithCast<TMark>(int index)
    {
        var f = this[index] as IFly<TMark>;
        if (f == null) { throw new InvalidCastException(); }
        return f;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IFly<TMark>> GetItemsWithCast<TMark>()
    {
        var items = this.Where(p => p is IFly<TMark>).Cast<IFly<TMark>>();
        return items;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TFlyer> GetItemsByType<TFlyer>() where TFlyer : IFly 
    {
        var items = this.Where(p => p.GetType() == typeof(TFlyer)).Cast<TFlyer>();
        return items;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that upcasting can have some performance implications depending on transaction volume, however is probably negligible for most scenarios.