# Can't assign methods that return value types to Func<dynamic>

Tags: c#, dynamic, func

I have a variable of type `Func<dynamic>` and I am trying to assign it a value. If I assign it to a method that returns a value type (e.g. `int`), I get the error

> 'int MethodName()' has the wrong return type

If I wrap the method in a lambda call, however, it works fine. Also methods that return reference types seem to work fine.

```
private string Test()
{
    return "";
}

private int Test2()
{
    return 0;
}

Func<dynamic> f = Test;           // Works
Func<dynamic> g = Test2;          // Does not
Func<dynamic> h = () => Test2();  // Works
```

What's wrong with the direct assignment case?

Comment: It's not just `dynamic`. If you change your `Func<dynamic>` to `Func<object>` you get the same error, and I think it's because boxing operation would get introduced indirectly, and compiler is not ok with that, but I can't find anything in the spec that would describe that situation.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek From the specs on delegate compatability, "For each value parameter (a parameter with no ref or out modifier), an identity conversion (§6.1.1) or implicit reference conversion (§6.1.6) exists from the parameter type in D to the corresponding parameter type in M."  There is an implicit conversion in this case, but it's not an identity or reference conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `dynamic` or `delegate TResult Func<out TResult>()`. You will see the same behavior in this code:

```
interface I<out T> { }
class C<T> : I<T> { }
...
I<int> a = new C<int>();
I<string> b = new C<string>();
I<object> x = a; // compiler error
I<object> y = b; // no compiler error
```

For some reason, value types like `int` will automatically cast to `object` or `dynamic`, but `I<int>` will not *automatically* cast to `I<object>` or `I<dynamic>`. I can't find where in the language reference this is specified.

The reason `Func<dynamic> h = () => Test2();` works in your code is because it only requires `int` to cast to `dynamic` implicitly, which is fine. It does not require `Func<int>` to cast to `Func<dynamic>` implicitly.

Comment: Full explanation by Eric Lippert: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4098434/1828879