# Inconsistency between IEnumerable as object

Tags: c#, covariance

I'm having trouble explaining the following behaviour in C#

```
class A {    }
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        IEnumerable<char> b = "sdf";
        IEnumerable<A> c = new List<A> { new A() };

        Console.WriteLine(a is IEnumerable<object>); //false
        Console.WriteLine(b is IEnumerable<object>); //false 
        Console.WriteLine(c is IEnumerable<object>); //true
    }
}
```

Why is only List of custom types recognized as IEnumerable< object>

Comment: Probably because only A is a reference type, int and char are a struct

Comment: int and char are **not** inherited from object. You can assign them to object because .net will automatic wrap them to a boxed object containing the value. Read the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: @SirRufo: `int` and `char` *are* inherited from `object` (e.g., `System.Object ` -> `System.ValueType` -> `System.Int32`). At least, while we're talking about .NET. Stop this madness, please. This is variance issue for value-types.

Comment: @Dennis Then please talk to Microsoft that the docs are totally wrong regarding boxing (see my link). Until that I take the docs as true

Comment: @SirRufo: you're confusing inheritance and memory representation/memory location.

Comment: @Dennis I am as confused as John Skeet - I can live with that :o)

Comment: This answer linked from the linked answer from Eric Lippert explained it nicely. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4098434/170196

Comment: @SirRufo: could you post JS citation, where he claims, that `int` (or `char`) isn't inherited from `object`?

Comment: @Dennis See the duplicate question link and the accepted answer

Comment: @SirRufo: where's citation about *inheritance*? Could you post it? :) We need boxing, because reference types and value types have different memory representation. Boxing isn't related to inheritance hierarchy. All value types (including `int`, `char`, etc) are implicitly inherited from `System.ValueType`, which, in turn, is inherited from `System.Object`.

Comment: @Dennis You are right (I just read the articles from Eric Lippert) with the inheritence