# Covariance workaround for generic using both value and reference types

Tags: c#, casting, covariance

Foreword: I understand that covariance doesn't currently work with value types (c.f. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12454932/1406230), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4098434/1406230)).

---

I have a generic type that can be simplified as follows:

```
public interface IDynamicValue<out T>
{
    T Get(Context context);
}
public abstract class DynamicValue<T> : IDynamicValue<T>
{
    public abstract T Get(Context context);
}
```

The type `T` is being used as both reference and value types in different situations.

Now I've run into something like the following situation:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public object thing;

    public string ObjectToString(Context context)
    {
        if (thing is IDynamicValue<object>)
        {
            return (thing as IDynamicValue<object>).Get(context).ToString();
        }

        return thing.ToString();
    }
}
```

Thanks to covariance, if I pass a `DynamicValue<string>` as the object, then it will successfully be converted to an `IDynamicValue<object>` and the `Get` function will be executed.

However, if I pass a `DynamicValue<int>`, it will not be converted (as mentioned, I understand why this happening), and `o.ToString()` will be returned.

What workaround exists that will allow me to execute the `Get(context)` function on both reference and value typed `DynamicValues` in this situation? Kudos for not using reflection, if possible :D

Comment: `ObjectToString` can accept only `object`? Not `IDynamicValue<T>`?

Comment: Correct, the provided object may or may not be an `IDynamicValue`, and if it is, it's not known what type of `IDynamicValue` that may be.

Comment: Use reflection is only way I can find out, but I don't sure if that it's what you want.

Comment: I'd hope there's some way more efficient than via reflection, but realise that may not exist. In either case, I'd appreciate if you add an answer showing how you'd use reflection to solve the problem ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, you can add an interface without generic and mark some classes with it:

```
public interface IDynamicValue
{
    object Get(Context context);
}

public interface IDynamicValue<out T>
{
    T Get(Context context);
}
```

And check:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public object thing;

    public string ObjectToString(Context context)
    {
        if (thing is IDynamicValue<object>)
        {
            return (thing as IDynamicValue<object>).Get(context).ToString();
        }

        if (thing is IDynamicValue)
        {
            return (thing as IDynamicValue).Get(context).ToString();
        }

        return thing.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, and surprisingly simple! This is how I adapted your solution: `public interface IDynamicValue { object GetAsObject(Context context); }`. Then I let `DynamicValue` inherit that interface, and simply used `public object GetAsObject(Context context) => (object)Get(context);`, covering all subclasses in one fell swoop. Thanks.